# Create XML document on GWT client side

Tags: xml, gwt, xml-generation

I'm trying to create some XML files on the client and then send them to the server (nothing special, just something like `<root><blabla>...</blabla>...</root>`).

Doing this by hand would be possible but extremely inflexible and I see myself making a lot of mistakes. So I was looking for a XML generator in GWT and found the "com.google.gwt.xml.client" Package. Sadly I cant find examples how to create XML documents with it. Can anybody provide me an example (or linke ot an examle)?

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example. To generate the following xml :

```
<root>
  <node1 attribute="test">
     my value
  </node1>
  <node2 attribute="anothertest"/>
</root>
```

You have to write the following code on the Java client side :

```
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = XMLParser.createDocument();

    Element root = doc.createElement("root");
    doc.appendChild(root);

    Element node1 = doc.createElement("node1");
    node1.setAttribute("attribute","test");
    node1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("my value"));
    doc.appendChild(node1);

    Element node2 = doc.createElement("node2");
    node2.setAttribute("attribute","anothertest");
    doc.appendChild(node2);

    System.out.println(doc.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well ok, your anser works but some things to append.

First you have to include

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML" />
```

in your *gwt.xml file (http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-xml-first-steps-with-comgooglegwtxmlerste-schritte-mit-gwt-und-xml-unter-comgooglegwtxml/2009/05/ )

second you use the following namespaces:

```
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is right, but there is a little mistake on it, **node1** and **node2** should be linked to **root**, not to **doc**.

So this line:

```
doc.appendChild(node1);
```

should really be:

```
root.appendChild(node1);
```